# LINQ - join with OR condition

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I've got two entities, Users and Friendships which look like:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        (...)
    }

    public class Friendship
    {
         public int SenderId { get; set; }
         public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
         (...)
    }
```

And I would like to create simple query which in SQL would look like:

```
    SELECT * FROM Users as U
    INNER JOIN Friendships as F ON U.UserId = F.ReceiverId OR U.UserId = F.SenderId
    Where U.Nick != VARIABLE
```

In other words I would like to select all friends of the user.

And I can't accomplish that. I've found solution where one creates two separate join queries with union and it works - but it's not efficient to create such query to db.

Answer (score 5):

Joins in LINQ are always equijoins. Basically you need multiple `from` clauses and a `where` clause:

```
var query = from u in db.Users
            where u.Nick != variable
            from f in db.Friendships
            where u.UserId == f.ReceiveId || u.UserId == f.SenderId
            select ...;
```

Now in LINQ to Objects there are probably more efficient ways of doing this - but I'd expect a SQL-based LINQ provider to generate a query which has a *good enough* execution plan. It may not actually create a JOIN in the SQL, but I'd expect it to be the same execution plan as the join you've shown.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework Core and this results in a cross join as opposed to a inner join

Comment: @jonmeyer: But a cross join that still gives the same results as the equivalent inner join? That wouldn't surprise me - as I said in the answer.

Comment: Just in case, you having problems with additional null checks in new nullable projects, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74531817/2441442)

Answer (score 2):

Simply write:

```
from U in db.Users
from F in Friendships.Where(x => U.UserId == F.ReceiverId || U.UserId == F.SenderId)
where U.Nick != VARIABLE
select new {u, f};
```

Comment: @JoeTuskan It'll do an inner join. (Check the queryplan)