# How to join with or condition? Cross Join is creating a IS NULL where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Basically I want to create an inner `or` join. In SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Discounts
JOIN DiscountArticles ON Discounts.ID = DiscountArticles.Discount
JOIN Articles ON (DiscountArticles.Article = Articles.ID OR DiscountArticles.ArticleGroup = Articles.ArticleGroup)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610510/2441442) says, it's not possible using entity framework, however we can use an cross join, which works fine on SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS GroupCount FROM Discounts
JOIN DiscountArticles ON Discounts.ID = DiscountArticles.Discount
CROSS JOIN Articles
WHERE (Articles.ID = DiscountArticles.Article OR Articles.ArticleGroup = DiscountArticles.ArticleGroup)
```

So I tried this:

```
var query = from discounts in _dbContext.Discounts
    join discountArticles in _dbContext.DiscountArticles on discounts.Id equals discountArticles.Discount
    from article in _dbContext.Articles
    where article.Id == discountArticles.Article || article.ArticleGroup.Value == discountArticles.ArticleGroup.Value
    select new
    {
        ArticleId = article.Id,
        DiscountId = discounts.Id
    };
```

However, this resolves into this this SQL query:

```
SELECT [a].[ID] AS [ArticleId], [d].[ID] AS [DiscountId]
FROM [Discounts] AS [d]
INNER JOIN [DiscountArticles] AS [d0] ON [d].[ID] = [d0].[Discount]
CROSS JOIN [Articles] AS [a]
WHERE ([a].[ID] = [d0].[Article]) OR (([a].[ArticleGroup] = [d0].[ArticleGroup]) OR (([a].[ArticleGroup] IS NULL) AND ([d0].[ArticleGroup] IS NULL)))
```

As you can see, there is an addtional check `OR (([a].[ArticleGroup] IS NULL) AND ([d0].[ArticleGroup] IS NULL))`, which is causing to return 6 time more results.

`ArticleGroup` is Nullable `Guid?` on both entities, so I guess it has something to do with it.

If I additional check it for null, I get the correct results:

```
where article.Id == discountArticles.Article ||
  article.ArticleGroup.HasValue && article.ArticleGroup == discountArticles.ArticleGroup
```

However, I also get an bigger where clause in SQL:

```
WHERE ([a].[ID] = [d0].[Article]) OR (([a].[ArticleGroup] IS NOT NULL) AND ([a].[ArticleGroup] = [d0].[ArticleGroup]))
```

Is it somehow possible to generate a Query, which is more like my second SQL example? Something like this:

```
WHERE (Articles.ID = DiscountArticles.Article OR Articles.ArticleGroup = DiscountArticles.ArticleGroup)
```

Comment: _"However, I also get an bigger where clause in SQL:"_ - and this is a problem exactly why?

Comment: _"so I guess it has something to do with it."_ - yes, cause EF Core tries to be consistent with C# null semantics where checking  two nulls for equality will result in `true`, while it is not correct for SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, it will create appropriate join. I do not think that you need CROSS JOIN here.

```cs
var query = 
    from discounts in _dbContext.Discounts
    join discountArticles in _dbContext.DiscountArticles on discounts.Id equals discountArticles.Discount
    from article in _dbContext.Articles
        .Where(article => article.Id == discountArticles.Article || article.ArticleGroup.Value == discountArticles.ArticleGroup.Value)
    select new
    {
        ArticleId = article.Id,
        DiscountId = discounts.Id
    };
```

According to null comparison, check this option [Using relational null semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/null-comparisons#using-relational-null-semantics). Bad here that it will affect all queries:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(sourceConnection, sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.UseRelationalNulls();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's creating an [other query](https://imgur.com/a/3GICrTb), but the null where clause seems to be the same

Comment: Added at the end of the answer link to documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising and the root cause. Just trying to figure out how to setup